# Is ioncube loader needed for curation suite plugin on wordpress?

Tags: ioncube

I have tried to installed Curation suite plugin in wordpress but while installed curation suite plugin which show me Error. The Error is  "Ioncube not Installed".Is Ioncube loader needed for Curation suite?

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot find any information to pinpoint the dependency of the ionCube Loader to the Curation suite, something in your setup needs the ionCube Loader.

You can simply [download the Loader Wizard from here](http://www.ioncube.com/loader-wizard/loader-wizard.zip). If you put extract this and put the files on your server, it should guide you through the installation.

Otherwise, you can download the [appropriate Loaders from here](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php) , put them onto your webserver, and add the following entry to your php.ini:

```
zend_extension = /path/to/loader/file
```

If you encounter any problems, ionCube also offers [free support at their helpdesk](http://support.ioncube.com)

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with ionCube.